# Discrete math relation properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am working on a homework assignment and I am having trouble understanding the problem. I feel as if my professor forgot part of the problem, but I would just like to double check and make sure I am not reading the problem incorrectly. This is the problem:

For <= relation on the set of integers, specify if <= is Reflexive(R), Antireflexive(AR),
Symmetric(S), Antisymmetric(AS), or Transitive(T). Show your analysis.

I am thinking that there is supposed to be a relational expression in there, or something like that. I know that <= can be reflexive, symmetric, and antisymmetric. Just curious that is all. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The relation $\leq$ is reflexive. To see this, consider some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $x\leq x$, by definition of $\leq$.
- By definition of anti-reflexive, $\leq$ is not antireflexive.
- The relation $\leq$ is not symmetric, as if $x\leq y$, $y\not\leq x$.
- The relation is antisymmetric, as if $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$, then $y=x$.
- This is transitive, as if $x\leq y\leq z$, then $x\leq z$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I was just unsure if there was supposed to be a relational expression that was supposed to be included. Thank you for your answer though. That really helps out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is reflexive (and therefore not anti-reflexive) since it's true for all elements that $x \leq x$ (since $x = x$ is true for all integers).  It's not symmetric however, since if $x \leq y$ is true then $y \leq x$ if false (unless $x = y$).  It is anti-symmetric since $\left(x \leq y \wedge y \leq x\right) \rightarrow x = y$ (i.e. $x$ and $y$ are the same integer).  Finally, it would be transitive because $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$ implies that $x \leq z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This really helps out a lot.